# A Humbled Response

Tags: rhyme, steganography

Well, I may not be able to match the rhyme or meter ...or spelling ...or punctuation skills of other puzzle creators on this site, but I thought I should still at least have a go...

> Well, I'm handing down the mantle- as [that mountain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42420/a-blooming-cheeky-response) dwarfs this ant hill
>   Though I.m honoured. lies he fed you. turning cheeks a rosy red colour.
>
> As each time I tr& defeating, it.s my iwn end that I'm meeting.
>   He continles climbing spires. I.ll just wallow in these swamps.
>
> But, this ain't just [dactyl prattle](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5306/various-virtuosic-variety#comment11540_5311) - 'tis a rapping riddle battle
>   So, I'll play no second fiddle. to his better rhyming prose.
>
> Yet I must admit I'm broken! -though his name here goes unspoken-
>   'Cos oith rsddles, what a dueler. He's the uedisputed champ!

What is/are the hidden message(s)?

Comment: Tangentially related: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice *[...] Also, this is not a dating site.*

Comment: You shouldn't be humbled. This is just as good as the others :P

Comment: @HughMeyers, I'm still waiting for the your response...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Well, I may not be able to match the rhyme or meter ...or spelling ...or punctuation skills of other puzzle creators on this site, but I thought I should still at least have a go...

This tells us where to look: at the errors in rhyme/meter, spelling, and punctuation.

---

**The first hidden message is given by**

> **the spelling errors in the poem.**

Bolding them up:

> Well, I'm handing down the mantle- as that mountain dwarfs this ant hill
>   Though I.m honoured. lies he fed you. turning cheeks a rosy red colour.
>
> As each time I tr **&** defeating, it.s my **i**wn end that I'm meeting.
>   He contin**l**es climbing spires. I.ll just wallow in these swamps.
>
> But, this ain't just dactyl prattle - 'tis a rapping riddle battle
>   So, I'll play no second fiddle. to his better rhyming prose.
>
> Yet I must admit I'm broken! -though his name here goes unspoken-
>   'Cos **o**ith r**s**ddles, what a dueler. He's the u**e**disputed champ!

So we have

> the letters **&ilose**, which should actually be **youwin**,

and the message is

> YOU WIN & I LOSE.

---

**The second hidden message is given by**

> <s>the punctuation errors in the poem</s> **the dots and dashes in the poem.**

Marking them with stars:

> Well, I'm handing down the mantle*-* as that mountain dwarfs this ant hill
>   Though I*.*m honoured*.* lies he fed you*.* turning cheeks a rosy red colour*.*
>
> As each time I tr& defeating, it*.*s my iwn end that I'm meeting*.*
>   He continles climbing spires*.* I*.*ll just wallow in these swamps*.*
>
> But, this ain't just dactyl prattle *-* 'tis a rapping riddle battle
>   So, I'll play no second fiddle*.* to his better rhyming prose*.*
>
> Yet I must admit I'm broken! *-*though his name here goes unspoken*-*
>   'Cos oith rsddles, what a dueler*.* He's the uedisputed champ!

So the message seems to be

> - .... .. ... - .. -- . or THIS TIME.

---

**The third hidden message is given by**

> **the rhyming 'errors' in the poem.**

Bolding them up:

> Well, I'm handing down the mantle- as that mountain dwarfs this ant hill
>   Though I.m honoured. lies he fed you. turning cheeks a rosy red **colour**.
>
> As each time I tr& defeating, it.s my iwn end that I'm meeting.
>   He continles climbing spires. I.ll just wallow in these **swamps**.
>
> But, this ain't just dactyl prattle - 'tis a rapping riddle battle
>   So, I'll play no second fiddle. to his better rhyming **prose**.
>
> Yet I must admit I'm broken! -though his name here goes unspoken-
>   'Cos oith rsddles, what a dueler. He's the uedisputed **champ**!

So we have

> the non-rhyming words "colour, swamps, prose, champ", which should be replaced by "hue, mires, riddle, ruler",

and the message is

> HUGH MEYERS - RIDDLE RULER.

---

Putting it all together, we get a single unified final message:

> **Hugh Meyers, riddle ruler - you win & I lose ... this time.**

Comment: I found another bit, seems this is multilayeres

Comment: And if you do the reverse?

Comment: @HughMeyers, why didn't you solve this one, it's all about you! :P

Comment: All looks good, except for the punctuation, but that's my fault not yours. In my rush/sleep deprivation, I lost track of my own puzzle and based the punctuation morse part directly off `.` and `-` rather than errors thereof, as I intended and you assumed (spelling "*this time*" -> "*Hugh Meyers - Riddle Ruler. You win & I lose... this time...*"). Just a reminder that, 1) @HughMeyers is indeed the master, and 2) I should listen to [my own advice](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/41677/5208) and not bash things out the door at 1am. :) Well done though.

Answer (score 10):

**The clue is at the top** where Alconja says

```
Well, I may not be able to match the rhyme or meter
```

 ...or 
**spelling** ...or **punctuation skills** of other puzzle creators on this site,
 but I thought I should still at least have a go...

So we need to look at the rhyme and meter, spelling and punctation skills

**Punctuation:** There are some hidden -s and .s in the text and excluding full stops (dots with a caps after them.)

> -... .. -. --.

which when translated from Morse Code gives

> BING

Which could be

> Relating to the website Bing?

And @RandAl'Thor found **spelling** - that the spelling mistakes you get

> & I lose

And fixing them you get

> You win

So

> You win & I lose

Which could be related to

> The rap battle mentioned

So **rhyme and meter** is left

I got stuck and Rand got it (of course :P) and the rhyme and meter is

The words that don't rhyme have synonyms that do and they are

> Hue Mires Riddle Ruler

So the message is:

> Hugh Meyers Riddle Ruler